# Django rest allow get but not list

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, get

I want to allow the `get` for retriving a single object to the guest users. But keep the `list` which retrives all items of that model in the database only for admins. But i am not sure how to seperate `get` and `list` because they both seem to be under the `get` from my point of view.

Below is my viewset:

```
class OrdersViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated|ReadOnly]
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    # parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
    model = Order
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['partial'] = True
        return super().update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

And my ReadOnly:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission, IsAuthenticated, SAFE_METHODS
class ReadOnly(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.method in SAFE_METHODS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `get_permission` function and `action`.

```py
class OrdersViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated|ReadOnly]
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    # parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
    model = Order
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['partial'] = True
        return super().update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            permission_classes = [IsAdmin]
        elif self.action == 'retrieve':
            permission_classes = [AllowAny]
        else:
            permission_classes = [ReadOnly]
    return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]
```